# How do I convert manpages/info files to EPUB?

Tags: ebook, man, epub, manpages, info

I like to read the manual pages on my e-reader. What is the best way to convert the manpages/info files into EPUBs?

Comment: EPUB is HTML in a zip file. Google for "man page to html", pick one of the many alternatives, add the extra files EPUB needs (again, google for examples). All of that can be easily scripted. I don't know of a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use
[Github manbook](https://github.com/nerab/manbook).
It contains two programs:

> The `manbook` command can be used to produce an eBook from one or more
> `man` pages.
>
> `mktoc` produces table-of-content files, suitable for MOBI files
> (Kindle, etc) from the HTML files in a directory.